# How to convert string array in another array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ajax call which returns an array of strings and I need to convert this array into a javascript array : I explain with examples :

my return from ajax call is like that :

```
 success: function (doc) {

doc.d[0] // =  "{ 'title': 'Espagne', 'start': '2016-05-24', 'end': '2016-05-25' }" 
doc.d[1] // = "{ 'title': 'Italie', 'start': '2016-05-18', 'end': '2016-05-20' }"
....
```

And I want to create a JavaScript Array like that :

```
 var countries = new Array();
 countries[0] = { 'title': 'Espagne', 'start': '2016-05-24', 'end': '2016-05-25' };
 countries[1] = { 'title': 'Italie', 'start': '2016-05-18', 'end': '2016-05-20' };
```

Have you an idea how to take the return string from doc.d and convert it to an array ?

If i do a thing like that :

```
var countries = new Array();
coutries[0] = doc.d[0]
```

it can't work

It is possible to use .map() or .push() to build a new array using doc.d ?

Comment: if you get a [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) conform string, you could use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Comment: It works ! But i have to add in my case : JSON.parse('['+doc.d+']')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just simply assign list to another variable

Try like this

```
var countries  = JSON.parse(doc.d);
```

Comment: This way countries will have values as string, not in object format.

Answer (score 2):

The `JSON.parse()` method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string.

```
JSON.parse(doc.d[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
doc.d[0] =  "{ 'title': 'Espagne', 'start': '2016-05-24', 'end': '2016-05-25' }" 
doc.d[1] = "{ 'title': 'Italie', 'start': '2016-05-18', 'end': '2016-05-20' }"

var arr = [];
if(doc.d.length)
{

    for(var i in doc.d)
    {
        arr.push(JSON.parse(doc.d[i]));
    }

    console.log(arr);
}
```

Else

```
doc.d[0] =  "{ 'title': 'Espagne', 'start': '2016-05-24', 'end': '2016-05-25' }" 
doc.d[1] = "{ 'title': 'Italie', 'start': '2016-05-18', 'end': '2016-05-20' }"

var arr = [];
if(doc.d.length)
{

    for(var i in doc.d)
    {
        arr.push(doc.d[i].split('"')[1]); //This way also you can do
    }

    console.log(arr);
}
```

So arr[0] will be same as object of doc.d[0] and so on.